# Is there a better workflow for TypeScript development?

Tags: typescript

Currently I'm using Typescript and Angular 1.4 with commonjs dynamic modules.

So, for development environment I use System.js that loads modules directly from source files (no need to build a bundle).

For production I use Webpack to create single bundle.

If I have a non-commonjs module I have to map it - separately for Webpack and System.js.

This makes me really sick - I'm thinking of good old script-tag times (which of course is almost impossible for application modules that has over hundred files, but it's OK for external libraries).

Is there a better workflow for Typescript with external modules ?
(would be great if i could map external bower modules in one place)

Comment: what kind of idjit edit "webpack" which is name of product into "web pack" - why ?

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a better workflow for Typescript with external modules

Just use webpack only. No gain in using two tools System.js + Webpack.

Comment: No do. " System.js that loads modules directly from source files (no need to build a bundle)" - how would I achieve this with webpack?

Comment: checkout webpack dev time workflow. Specifically `--watch`

Comment: OMG, man - whatever you write, whatever I checkout U will not make webpack a dynamic module loader. It makes bundle. you check out webpack server if you want but... AS I STATED VERY CLEARLY making bundle is not an option.... jeeeez